# Load json data after ajax submit success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

[image]i try to create tags form with textextjs
but i have a problem with ajax to call new data after another ajax success submit

this is my code to call json

```
var tagload =   $('#textarea')
    .textext({
        plugins : 'autocomplete filter tags ajax',
        ajax : {                
            url: "<?= base_url() ?>admin_ajx/tags_ajx/data_tags",
            dataType : 'json',
            cacheResults : true
        }
    });
```

and this is my code to submit new data to json

```
        $(document).ready(function(){  
           $(".save_new_tags").click(function(){
                var data = $('.add_new_tags').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "<?= base_url() ?>admin_ajx/tags_ajx/add_tags",
                            data: data,
                            success: function() {                                                                             
                            $(".add_new_tags")[0].reset();
                            alert("Post Success!");                                
                            tagload.ajax.reload();
                        }                                    
                    });
                });
            });
```

how to load new data, after success submit new data

i thinks the problem is here 
 **cacheResults : true**

i'am still looking for solution

Comment: what exactly is happening that shouldn't be and what troubleshooting steps have you already taken? i find it difficult to grasp your problem statement

Comment: define second ajax call in one function, and call that function first ajax call success.

Comment: i try to create multiple tags, but after submit new tags, new data didnt apprear to textarea form ..

Comment: i already try to make first ajax as a function and call after ajax success, new data can be load, but the value its out of the form, this is the code i used                                 $(document).ready(function(){load_tag(); });

Comment: as a complete sidenote, i would suggest using select2

Comment: can you suggest me link too ??

Answer (score 0):

There is not AJAX property on the returned jQuery selection in `tagload`.

The example with `cacheResults` property set to `true` assumes that [the backend is returning all possible results](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/jquery-textext/blob/1.3.1/src/js/textext.plugin.ajax.js#L75).

Since you're allowing for updates to the possible values, this isn't the situation any longer.

Removing `cacheResults` option or set it to `false` should have your tag suggestions updated.

You could also keep the `cacheResults` option set to `true` and update the suggestions on the `Textext` instance after fetching the tags using `$.ajax`.

```
var opts = {                
  url: "<?= base_url() ?>admin_ajx/tags_ajx/data_tags",
  dataType : 'json',
  cacheResults : true
}

var tagload = $('#textarea')
    .textext({
      plugins : 'autocomplete filter tags ajax',
      ajax : opts
    });

$(document).ready(function(){  
   $(".save_new_tags").click(function() {
     //...

      $.ajax(opts).done(function(suggestions) {
         var textExts = $('#textarea').textext()[0]
         textExts.ajax()._suggestions = suggestions
     });
  });
});
```

Comment: problem is, when iam not insert anything to text form, new data will appear well, but if iam post after put one or more tags, new data couldnt appear